# Does any python library allow for running an application and giving it input?

Tags: library, python

I'm attempting to automate PsExec using a python script. I'd like to be able to read computer names to access and automatically run commands on all of them while getting the output. Is there any python library or other application that will allow me to run an application while still automatically giving input and getting output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard python library `subprocess` has `popen` and *since 3.5* `run` both of which support piping to `stdin` and from both `stdout` and `stderr` to do this. Currently `run` is the recommended use where it can handle the required functionality. See the [documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) for details.

Be sure to read the [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) section carefully. If there is expected to be a lot of output it is often better to use setting stdout &/or stderr to a writable open file handle to avoid possible deadlocks or memory overflow.

If you want to carry on processing while an external program executes (possibly controlling input & output) use [asyncio.create_subprocess_exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.create_subprocess_exec) in python > 3.5.

You might also wish to take a look at [GRR Rapid Response](https://grr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which will allow a more pythonic method of doing similar tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get the output of a command by redirecting output to a file and reading that file. The following should work on most platforms:

```
from os import system
system("yourcommand 1> logfile.txt 2>&1") # add " &" (without quotes) to the end of the command string to skip waiting for execution to complete. Note that you'll need to check if your process is complete by using some other method.
result = open("logfile.txt", "r").read()
```

See here for additional information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file